# configuring pycharm to compile scss and then run flask in the server

Tags: python, bash, flask, sass, pycharm

> I have been searching for this problem for the past few hours. I
>   thought documenting it would be helpful for me in the future and for
>   anyone struggling with the same thing

I have a flask web app. and each and every time before testing it, I compile scss files using the command

```
scss file.scss file.css
```

Then I run flask with those three commands

```
source venv/bin/activate
export FLASK_APP=run.py
flask run
```

as you can see, this is pretty monotonous. how can I make this faster? can't I just press 'run' somewhere and then all of these command get executed, and maybe show me the errors and such?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can just press run and have everything done using PyCharm.

**configuring flask:**

following this excellent [link](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/dev/cli/#pycharm-integration). Here are the steps:

1. run > edit configuration
2. Script: file/path/venv/bin/flask
3. scrip parameters: run
4. environment vars: FLASK_APP=run.py
5. working directory: file/path/to/where/the/run.py/is
6. unclick the PYTHONPATH options (1 & 2)

**compiling scss before running automatically:**

1. file > settings/preferences
2. tools > file watchers
3. +
4. scss
5. ok